# structure like array

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, firebird

I am selecting 2 columns from my database - `PPID` and `NAME`. I want to store that two values related.

So let's say now we have this:

```
|PPID |NAME
|1    |Admin
|2    |Aleksa
|3    |Marija
|4    |Predrag
|5    |Bojana
```

Now in combobox, I display `Names`, and when someone press for example `Predrag`, I want to have his `ppid (4)` for further usage.

I tried with structures but it didn't go well. If you have something on mind write me. Have on mind that this example has 5 rows, but in real I do not know how much rows there is, so it can't be static.

Comment: `Dictionary<String, int>`? If Name is unique

Comment: See MSDN: [Collections (C#) > Kinds of Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654013.aspx#Anchor_1)

Comment: Name is not unique, ppid is but as i get it, i can use the same but <int, string>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) and bind your combobox to the Dictionary.

For example (assuming PPID is unique):

```
Dictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                {1, "Admin"},
                {2, "Aleksa"},
                {3, "Marija"},
                {4, "Predrag"},
                {5, "Bojana"}
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

how about writing a class and let each person in your database get its own instance?

```
class YourClass

{ 
public integer PPID {get;set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}

static void Main()
{
// Just an example...
// SQL command already executed, data readers declared and so on...

int i=0;

YourClass[] arr = new YourClass[];

while(yourDataReader.Read()){
  arr[i] = new YourClass();
  arr[i].PPID = yourDataReader.GetInt32(0);
  arr[i].Name = yourDataReader.GetString(1);
}
```